# How does Djangos user permissions work?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, permissions

I am lacking of basic understanding of the user permission model of django. 
What I basically want is that a user can delete its own account with a button. But I fear that I grant the user more permissions to delete things than the user should. Like deleting other users?!?

So i guess i have to use something like

```
myuser.user_permissions.add(permission, permission, ...)
```

I red https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

So do I need to write model methods, which i give granted permission to the user for execution?

Comment: Remember you can also create groups, add permissions to them and later include users in, so they can have this permissions in a more ordered way.  It could be made via django admin site or by code on views (depending on what you prefer or consider more apropiate).

Answer (score 1):

Just to let an user to delete his own account you don't really need the permission system. You can do it in a view like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def delete_my_account(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        logout(request)
        user.delete()
        (then redirect, render a template or whatever)
```